# What is the complexity of getting a symmetry element from a square matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, time-complexity

I'd like to get the position (a pair of indices `(i, j)`) of a symmetry element (*`Aij=Aji`*, *i≠j*) from a *square boolean* matrix *A*. Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([ [0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 0]])

for (i, j), value in np.ndenumerate(A):
    if i>j and A[i,j] == A[j,i]:
        print(i,j)              # output: (2, 1)
        break
```

Assume that *A* is a square matrix of size *n*. It takes `n^2/4` steps on average to get such a element, therefore the time complecity is *o(n^2)*, right?

Is there a more efficient solution if *A* is a *sparse* boolean matrix?

Comment: Assuming it is O(1) to get each value out of `np.ndenumerate(A)`.

Comment: Do you want to print all symetries or just one?

Comment: @MuliYulzary, one is enough for me.

Comment: @MuliYulzary: Why would it matter?  O() is about worst case, which in this case would mean that there are no symmetries to be found, and all possible ones would have to be checked.

Comment: Worst case will be n^2 anyway.

Comment: It's obviously going to have to take O(n^2) time. The only thing that gives you any information about whether Aij=Aji is looking at both cells. You can't do any better than linear search.

Comment: @user2357112, thx, what happens if *A* is a boolean matrix and sparse matrix?

Comment: Actually you could iterate from both ends and maybe cut this to (n^2)/2

Comment: @SparkandShine: Depends how sparse it is and what sparse matrix format you're working with. For example, if you can efficiently look up single element values (as with a DOK matrix), and if the matrix is sparse enough to justify a sparse matrix format, then just trying random positions until you find a symmetry is going to be efficient.

Comment: You can probably get all symmetries in O(n log n) where n is the number of nonzeros by sorting the tuples `(val, max(i, j), min(i,j))` and looking for equal elements with `i!=j`. A boolean matrix can be represented as a set of `(i,j)` tuples and you can efficiently find symmetries by checking membership of `(j,i)` in the set.

Comment: It may be even easier to look for a symmetry of zeros if the matrix is sparse because the probability finding two zeros (assuming the positions are uncorrelated) is `(1 - nnz/n^2)^2 ~= 1 - 2 nnz/n^2`, so you may get one in just a few tries by picking random indices.